# CSS condition for IMG smaller than X

Tags: css, conditional-statements

I'm looking for a CSS example that only selects IMG elements that are smaller than X px.

I assumed that something similar to "@media (max-width: X px)" could be possible, but I couldn't fiddle the right combination.

Maybe you have the compelling idea.

Comment: There is no such thing in CSS. Width is *stated* in CSS not *detected*

Comment: I think you might be looking into the wrong language to solve your problem. You would be better of using JavaScript or jQuery to solve this.  please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Comment: i try mostly to avoid JS, but yeah, if nothing like this exist, the easiest way would be JS with adding a class.